# How to get the current user's home directory in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

How can I get the path to the current User's home directory?

Ex: In Windows, if the current user is "guest" I need "C:\Users\guest"

My application will run on most of the Windows versions (XP, Vista, Win 7).

Comment: Are you looking for the current path, or home directory?  Please put some effort into asking your question (and wording/spelling it correctly) if you'd like others to put effort into helping you.

Comment: I apologize. I need to get the user's path. In windows 7 each logged user have a account under the folder "users". If my login account is HPFE, i need to get the path "C:\users\hpfe".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the function [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx).  This function is preferred over querying environment variables since the latter can be modified to point to a wrong location.  The documentation contains an example, which I repeat here (slightly adjusted):

```
#include <Shlobj.h>  // need to include definitions of constants

// .....

WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_PROFILE, NULL, 0, path))) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: sweet, didn't know about this one.

Comment: you mean, the user location can be confgured any location?

Comment: Thanks for the better solution.

Comment: `SHGetFolderPath` meanwhile is deprecated, and the successor `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is not available on Windows XP.

Comment: For anyone using QT that wants to get string out of this use this > QString::fromWCharArray(path)

Comment: DEPRECATED! (from the proved link documentation)

Comment: Is there any way to find this via the command line from within windows?

Answer (score 5):

I have used %USERPROFILE% to get path the current User's home directory.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the environment variables, in this particular case you want `%HOMEPATH%` and combine that with `%SystemDrive%`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: Is there any chance, System Drive can be "C:" and HomePath can be E:\Users\{username}

Comment: possibly - http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7 - but that would be just a "simlink" so C:\Users would point to E:\Users so the path will be resolved anyways

Comment: This might be the case for Windows 7, but I'm quite confident that at least under Windows XP you can actually move profile directories to another volume, so you should never use the `SystemDrive` environment variable.  Please use `SHGetFolderPathW`, it is always correct, works on all supported Windows versions, and is easier to use.

Comment: It is **`%HOMEDRIVE%`**, NOT `%SystemDrive%`, that you should be using with `%HomePath%`.

Answer (score -2):

Approach 1:

```
#include <Shlobj.h>

std::string desktop_directory(bool path_w)
{
    if (path_w == true)
    {
        WCHAR path[MAX_PATH + 1];
        if (SHGetSpecialFolderPathW(HWND_DESKTOP, path, CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, FALSE))
        {
            std::wstring ws(path);
            std::string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());
            return str;
        }
        else return NULL;
    }
}
```

Approach 2:

```
#include <Shlobj.h>

LPSTR desktop_directory()
{
    static char path[MAX_PATH + 1];
    if (SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(HWND_DESKTOP, path, CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, FALSE)) return path;
    else return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain the difference between the two please?

Comment: Your code returns the desktop directory, not the home directory as requested. Replace CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY with CSIDL_PROFILE (and rename the functions appropriately) to return the user's home directory as requested.

Comment: Additionally, approach 2 returns a pointer to static memory, which will break if this is used in a process shared by multiple users. If two calls to approach 2 return different values, the first return value will "magically" change, because the second call will reuse the same memory space for its return value as the first call. Do not use approach 2 in production without careful consideration.

Comment: Furthermore, approach 1 does not return a value on all code paths (such as if path_w is false)

Comment: Also, SHGetSpecialFolderPathW is no longer supported, currently replaced by SHGetKnownFolderPath.

Comment: returning NULL instead of std::string is probably a very bad idea. You could use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.